# How to add custom options to Product Sort By drop down in Magento?

Tags: magento, sorting, product

I have developed my first Magento site and my client has asked me to do something I cannot
figure out how to do.

Currently, in any given category, the product Sort By dropdown contains the following options:

```
Position
Name
Price
```

I need to change that to:

```
Relevance
Popular
Price
```

How do I do this?

Comment: what does relevance and popular refer to?

Comment: (Off the top of my head) check /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php near the bottom. That's where position is being set. That should give you some clues. You can also choose other attributes in the backend to be used for sorting. CATALOG >> ATTRIBUTES >> MANAGE ATTRIBUTES.

Answer (score 2):

This is all to do with your attributes. Say you have an attribute in

> Admin>Catalog>Attributes>Manage Attributes>[attribute like: 'name' etc>Properties>Frontend Properties>"Used for sorting in product listing".

you need to select **Yes**. Then once you have selected **Yes** in the attributes you want to sort by, go into

> Admin>Catalog>Manage Categories>[Select your category you are displaying the drop down in]>Display Settings tab,

then select the Attributes you want to be sorted by in the Available Product Listing Sort By list. If the box is greyed out, untick the Use All Available Attributes checkbox. You may need to hold Ctrl  and click on the attributes to select multiple values. Then Save.

Done

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the product type with drop-down is Configurable Product. You can see these three options,

```
Position
Name
Price
```

You can locate these options under,

```
Catalog->Manage Products->Your_product->Associated Products->Super product attributes configuration
```

Also, you can directly update this into,

```
Relevance
Popular
Price
```

In case if these fields are missing, you can search for attributes named, `Position||Name||Price.` 
You can locate the label,

```
Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes->Your_attribute->Manage Labels/Options.
```